# How to make a deterministic finite state machine that accepts only a string of certain number of 0s?

Tags: finite-automata, state-machine

How to make a deterministic finite state machine that accepts only a string of certain number of 0s? for example, a machine that accepts only 00000 (5 zeros, not 4 or 6 zeros)

Comment: What specifically about this question is giving you trouble?

Comment: @Welbog I have tried to draw the above machine with 6 states: \n    a>0>b>0>c>0>d>0>e>0>f  ( f is the final state, and input 1 take them back to state a). But i think there should be a easier and shorter way.

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to build a DFA of less than n+1 states to count n consecutive zeros because the states of your automaton represent its only memory. You need to count to 5 (starting from 0) for example for accepting '00000', and that means 6 states:

[image]